# Umbrella Imports with Dart/Flutter

Tags: interface, dart, package, flutter, umbrella

I am developing a plugin for Dart (Flutter). I have split up the source into many different implementation files to keep things clean and avoid having one massive file.

The problem is, I don't want users to have to import tons of source files whenever they want to use my package.

Is there any way, in flutter or Dart itself, to be able to declare some sort of umbrella interface?

Comment: You can create exports in a single file and have them import that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your plugin, you have a `lib` folder. Create a `lib/src` sub-folder and move the bulk of your implementation files there. It's typical to be left with just one file in `lib` e.g. `someplugin.dart`.

In there you can have any top level classes or functions but this is where you include the implementation source files using the `export` directive.

Here's an example from the google_sign_in plugin, from `google_sign_in.dart`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' show hashValues;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show MethodChannel;
import 'package:meta/meta.dart' show visibleForTesting;

import 'src/common.dart'; // this import is only required if used by some top level
                          // class lower down this file

export 'src/common.dart'; // this export means that your plugin's users don't need
                          // to import it themselves
```